# Least quadratic equation

Tags: math-mode

how do I write this formula in latex? Thanks[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It is usually best to show a small [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of what you've tried so far, as pure do-it-for-me questions are not popular and not of much value for future visitors of the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$\min_u \| r^* + \delta - Gu\|_2^2$
```

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  You probably want a display environment to get the `u` under the `\min`, or you can add `\limits`

Answer (score 3):

Just a small change from @G.Gare's answer, the following puts the `u` underneath the `\min` in text mode, also it includes a displayed variant using `equation`:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,preview]{standalone}

\begin{document}
$\min\limits_u \| r^* + \delta - Gu\|_2^2$
\begin{equation}
  \min_u \| r^* + \delta - Gu\|_2^2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]